# DNS resolver issue Composer 2

Tags: php, composer-php

**Composer version: 2.0.4**

**OS: macOS 10.15.7**

When I run composer diagnose I get DNS resolver issue as seen in the attached image

I am able to ping getcomposer.org, packagist.org, github.com - all sites from the terminal.

`curl -i packagist.org -L` also works as expected without any error

Yet with composer diagnose I am getting DNS resolver issue

This started happening after I upgraded PHP from 7.4.1 to 7.4.12 and updating to composer 2

What could be the issue and how can I fix it

**As searchable text code - composer 2.0.4 diagnose failing**

```sh
$ composer diagnose
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: FAIL
The following exception probably indicates you have misconfigured DNS resolver(s)
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] Resolving timed out after 10003 milliseconds
Checking https connectivity to packagist: FAIL
The following exception probably indicates you have misconfigured DNS resolver(s)
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] Resolving timed out after 10003 milliseconds
Checking github.com rate limit: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] Resolving timed out after 10004 milliseconds
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys: 
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
Checking composer version: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] Resolving timed out after 10002 milliseconds
Composer version: 2.0.4
PHP version: 7.4.12
PHP binary path: /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.12/bin/php
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020
cURL version: 7.73.0 libz 1.2.11 ssl OpenSSL/1.1.1h
zip extension: OK
```

**Screenshot - composer 2.0.4 diagnose failing**
[image]

I just uninstalled composer 2.0.4 and installed composer 1.10.17 with rest of the packages/apps as it is and it runs without any DNS resolver error

**As searchable text code composer 1.10.17 diagnose**

```sh
composer diagnose
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys: 
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
Checking composer version: You are not running the latest stable version, run `composer self-update` to update (1.10.17 => 2.0.4)
Composer version: 1.10.17
PHP version: 7.4.12
PHP binary path: /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.12/bin/php
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020
```

**Screenshot - composer 1.10.17 diagnose**
[image: composer 2.0.4 diagnose failing]

So does it mean that composer 2.0.4 has some issues? or is incompatible with my setup of other apps/packages?

I want to use composer 2.x, so what do I do to make it work?

Comment: For me it helped to disconnect and reconnect my internet connection.

Comment: I had the same problem, but this post resolved it:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error/91595#91595

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the end, it's not a "composer" problem, but of the underlying connectivity technology. Composer 2 uses `curl` by default, whereas Composer 1 used PHP streams... and apparently they are not equally sensitive or forgiving to different network configurations and misconfigurations.

Some things to check and re-check:

- Your DNS settings. Check that there are no wrongly configured entries. Just for the sake of it change if you can your DNS provider to a "known good" one. E.g. Cloudflare's (`1.1.1.1`), or Google's (`8.8.8.8`, `8.8.4.4`), and remove all other entries.
- IPV6 connectivity. You many need to disable it if you have it enabled, since some users reported issues with it.
- Disable any VPNs you may be using to connect to the Internet, since they may interfere with your connectivity.

On [this issue](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/9376) some users have commented on similar problems.

Comment: Adding `8.8.8.8` and `1.1.1.1` to the top of  ` DNS Servers` in Network settings seems to work. I didn't even have to disable IPV6. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, DNS wasn't working. https://askubuntu.com/a/1353199/48214 helped me.

Comment: thank you @Ryan, turns out my resolv.conf symlinked to laravel valet that i uninstalled earlier

Comment: "Disable any VPNs" - that was the problem.

Answer (score 3):

if you have any VPN running try to disable and check again in my case that was the issue .

Answer (score 1):

On my work laptop (Mac) I had to have my employer DNS server as first DNS server, which failed to response when I wasnt in the network (or connected via VPN). I had to manually change it to use another DNS server first instead. VPN still works by this change. (For now?)

[image: network settings]

Answer (score 0):

I was solved this problem assigning a network

```
# docker network create --subnet=172.19.0.0/24 net-composer
# docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/app  --interactive --tty --network net-composer   composer install
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `ipconfig /flushdns` in cmd.
It works on me.

Answer (score -2):

For Ubuntu the configuration file /etc/resolv.conf contains information that allows a computer connected to a network to resolve names into addresses.

Change it to, for example, Google's DNS servers:

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

Hope this will resolve the issue.